# connecting to my local virtualized debian

Tags: networking, connection, debian, virtualbox

I have installed Debian as a VirtualBox guest on Windows XP. Now I have installed ssh and apache on this virtualized Debian yet I couldn't find a way to connect. I have already tried "10.0.0.2", "10.0.2.2" and inet addresses I get from running "ifconfig". (I can get the "it works!" page of apache2 when I try 127.0.0.1 under guest Debian.

I will be greatful for any tips

Comment: Might want to mention VirtualBox in the main question, not just the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to refer to [section 6.4.1](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.0.4/UserManual.pdf) of the manual to set up port forwarding with the default NAT setup.